# How to measure RPM from vehicle tires? Wheel Speed Sensor

Tags: arduino, sensor, raspberry-pi, infrared, hall-effect

I'm looking for a Wheel Speed Sensor to use it with a Raspberry Pi project to measure RPMs from a vehicle tires, however, I can only found sensor devices that I can't use with vehicle tires, they are for smaller purposes.

There are several ways to do it:

- Hall Effect
- Reed Switch
- IR Sensor

I've found some sensors from companies but they are builded for specific devices from them.

I hope to receive some help from you guys! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This technology already exists for ABS brake sensors.  Rings on the axle have spaced magnets combined with a simple 12vdc sensor.  [Check this out.](https://www.reed-sensor.com/applications/automotive/anti-lock-braking-system-abs/)

Comment: I see, I could use Reed Switch or Hall effect sensor, the thing is to have candidates to work with the Raspberry Pi. I don't know if you could suggest me products

Comment: Your easiest path to success will be to visit your local auto parts store (or their website), O'Reilly, Autozone, NAPA, or some such, and ask for the parts.  Though most cars today should have ABS technology, I certainly know my 2003 Ford Escape does, so hand them that car and ask for the ABS sensor and the ABS axle ring.  They'll know what you're talking about.

Comment: It's for Chevrolet Camaro 2015, I'm planning to use Reed Sensor, however, I have nothing clear yet with a sensor that could work easly with... This looks more complicated